# Not able to update a package

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, updates

I have been told that the newest **package 1.8.2** is available.
But I am not able to upgrade m17n-db package.

```
# apt-get --only-upgrade install m17n-db
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
m17n-db is already the newest version (1.8.0-3).
```

I tried "apt-get update" command and it still shows the version 1.8.0

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; are we to guess?  *deb* packages are built for a specific release; so we're somewhat limited without knowing your OS/release detail.  The package I see in your paste is *latest* for three *supported* releases, but not for all; start by working out what you're actually running?

Comment: The latest version of the m17n-db package is not available in the default repositories of any version of Ubuntu including the Ubuntu 23.10mdevelopment version.

Answer (score 0):

"*I have been told that the newest package 1.8.2 is available*"

You have perhaps misunderstood.

A new upstream release of that software, 1.8.2, has indeed occurred.
But it's not a **package**.
Nobody has yet packaged that new release for Debian or Ubuntu.

See for yourself the status of the package maintainers at Debian: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/m17n-db

After the new version is packaged for Debian, the new version will be merged into a future release of Ubuntu.

Comment: what is needed for it to become a "package"?

Comment: A "package" allows the automation of installing, upgrading, configuring, and removing software in a consistent manner. A human volunteer must do the packaging, just as human volunteers did all the previous packaging. So what is needed is a willing volunteer to learn the process (see http://mentors.debian.net), or enough free time by an experienced volunteer to do the job.